# Postgres 8.3.1 centroid

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis, centroid

I am trying to create a centroid for a polygon using British National Grid coordinates
Below is my code

```
CREATE TABLE PROJECT.CINEMAS
(CINEMA_ID INTEGER NOT NULL,
CINEMA_NAME VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
ADDRESS_NUMBER INTEGER NOT NULL,
POST_CODE VARCHAR(8) NOT NULL,
STREET VARCHAR (25) NOT NULL,
TOWN VARCHAR (25) NOT NULL,
OPENING_TIME TIME NOT NULL,
CLOSING_TIME TIME NOT NULL,
);

/* Add a geometry column containing point coordinates*/ 

SELECT ADDGEOMETRYCOLUMN('project','cinemas', 'COORDINATES_GEOM', '27700','POLYGON',2);

/* Create a cinema centroid geometry column

SELECT ADDGEOMETRYCOLUMN('project','cinemas', 'CENTROID', '27700','POINT',2);

INSERT INTO PROJECT.CINEMAS 
VALUES
(1,'ODEON LEICESTER SQUARE', 24, 'WC2H 7LQ', 'LEICESTER SQUARE', 'LONDON', '11:00:00 AM','11:00:00 PM',GeometryFromText('POLYGON((529901 180738,529944 180745, 529947 180717, 529906 180710, 529905 180719,529902 180718,529900 180727,529903 180729,529901 180738)',27700),ST_Centroid('POLYGON((529901 180738,529944 180745, 529947 180717, 529906 180710, 529905 180719,529902 180718,529900 180727,529903 180729,529901 180738)'));
```

Any ideas why this doesn't work?

Comment: 1. *What* doesn't work. Do you get errors, smoke, alien invasion? 2. Please don't tell me you're really using a version of PostgreSQL that's not only end-of-life but missing 22 bug fix updates? http://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/

Comment: Thanks for replying! The error I get is:ERROR:  parse error - invalid geometry    As for the version I am using, I am being forced to use it for this project through a virtual machine so cannot change it.

Comment: Also: 8.3 is de-supported now. You should *really* plan for an upgrade to a more up-to-date version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple things,

You forgot a closing ) in the POLYGON strings

should be

```
GeometryFromText('POLYGON((529901 180738,529944 180745, 529947 180717, 529906 180710, 529905 180719,529902 180718,529900 180727,529903 180729,529901 180738))',27700)
```

You'll need to convert the polygon string into a geometry before passing the value into st_centroid function

```
ST_Centroid(GeometryFromText('POLYGON((529901 180738,529944 180745, 529947 180717, 529906 180710, 529905 180719,529902 180718,529900 180727,529903 180729,529901 180738))'))
```

SO...

```
INSERT INTO PROJECT.CINEMAS 
VALUES (1,'ODEON LEICESTER SQUARE', 24, 'WC2H 7LQ', 'LEICESTER SQUARE', 'LONDON', '11:00:00 AM','11:00:00 PM',
GeometryFromText('POLYGON((529901 180738,529944 180745, 529947 180717, 529906 180710, 529905 180719,529902 180718,529900 180727,529903 180729,529901 180738))',27700), 
ST_Centroid(GeometryFromText('POLYGON((529901 180738,529944 180745, 529947 180717, 529906 180710, 529905 180719,529902 180718,529900 180727,529903 180729,529901 180738))')));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Works perfectly now. Such an obvious error looking back at it now!

Answer (score 0):

If the error is "parse error - invalid geometry" then you have an invalid geometry definition and need to fix it.

Try separating out your geometry and doing SELECT  to see which one is wrong. I'm guessing it's the parameter to ST_Centroid.

Oh - and then, upgrade PostgreSQL to *at least* 8.3.23 - that's still unsupported, but at least it's got all the bug-fixes. Ideally upgrade to 9.2.

If you can't upgrade, see if you can't be removed from this project - if the database corrupts then presumably you'll end up being responsible.